# Can we retrieve data from realtime database of firebase in a dropdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dropdown

I am trying to retrieve list of shop names that I have saved in realtime database in flutter.
I want them in a drop down.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. If you're having a hard time making it work in your own project, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the link please, as it contains guidance to maximize the chances that someone can help you.